# How to access nested dictionary in dart?

Tags: dart, flutter

I have this code:

```
 class Dev {
     static final config = const {
       'endpoints': const {
         'signIn': '/v1/auth/sign_in',
       },
       'apiBaseUrl': 'localhost:3000'
     };
    }
```

Im trying to access to the signIn property in the config variable, when i do config['endpoints'] it access the property correctly, but when i try

```
var signInEndpoint = config['endpoints']['signIn'];
```

It doesn't work, same when i try

```
var endpoints = config['endpoints'];
var signInEndpoint = endpoints['signIn'];
```

How can i correctly access signIn property in variable?, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because the `endPoints` value is an `Object` not `dynamic`, try this:

```
var signInEndpoint = (Dev.config['endpoints'] as dynamic)['signIn'];
```

Answer (score 1):

@Juan you tried two approaches know,

1. ```
   var signInEndpoint = config['endpoints']['signIn'];
   ```

   which can fixed as per @diegoveloper's suggestion
2. ```
   var endpoints = config['endpoints'];
   var signInEndpoint = endpoints['signIn'];
   ```

   can be fixed like

   ```
   Map endpoints = config['endpoints']; //Map<String, String> will be much better
   var signInEndpoint = endpoints['signIn'];
   ```

**Additional information:**

I prefer **not** having `dynamic` type as it will create runtime errors only (no compile time error with dynamic/Object).

In your case `Dev.config` is of `Map<String, Object>`. Object can be **casted** to **anything** and it will create runtime errors.

So I changed the `Dev` class a bit. Please have a look

```
class Dev {
  static final Map<String, Map<String, String>> config = const {
    'endpoints': const {
      'signIn': '/v1/auth/sign_in',
      'apiBaseUrl': 'localhost:3000'
    },
  };
}
var signInEndpoint = Dev.config['endpoints']['signIn'] //will work
```

or like this

```
class Dev {

  static final Map<String, String> endpoints = const {
    'signIn': '/v1/auth/sign_in',
  };
  static final Map<String, String> config = const {
    'baseUrl': 'localhost:3000',
    'other': 'others'
  };
}
var signInEndpoint = Dev.endpoints['signIn']
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this has given me more options to work with, i think i will use the second approach you have given me.

Comment: Glad that it helped you